# How to append a date to all files in a directory without touching sub-directories via bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

I'm currently taking a class for Operating Systems and we're learning to do bash scripts as part of the curriculum. I need to append the date to all the files in a directory without touching sub-directories via a script. I've been to cobble up a one-liner script that will append the date to all the files, but it hits the folders in the current directory as well.

```
for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "$f-$(stat -c %Y "$f" | date +%Y%m%d)"; done
```

This'll append the date to the end of the filename, but like I said, it hits the directories under it. I'm currently using version 4.1.2 of bash on RedHatLinux.

I'm confused as all get out because of how inexeperienced with Unix I am (I'm primarily a Windows user), so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to limit this to only files. Perhaps a if/then test to see if `$f` is a file or directory?

Comment: With that bash version number you might be vulnerable to [shellshock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bu)

Comment: This would be relatively easy using a one line find command you realize which could be used in a bash script.

Comment: @Anthon I'm technically remoting in via Telnet through Putty to the server at my school. We've got one hell of a paranoid Admin who runs the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As slm already indicated you can test for `$f` to be a regular file. While learning I would change the script to not be a one liner, they tend to be harder to read and maintain:

```
for f in *
do 
  if [ -f "$f" ]
  then
    mv -- "$f" "$f-$(stat -c %Y "$f" | date +%Y%m%d)"
  fi 
done
```

(you can always fold this later by inserting `;` and deleting newlines)

The `-f` tests the argument to be a regular file (not a device or directory), there are other tests as well (`-d` for directory e.g, so you could test `if [ ! -d "$f" ]` as well in this case).

Comment: `$(stat -c %Y "$f" | date +%Y%m%d)` do the same jobs twice. `%Y`(as and `%y`) is the file's last modification time. So it is useful to receive it from `date` directly: `mv -- "$f" "f-$(date +%Y%m%d -r "$f")`

Comment: @Costas I didn't really look at that part of the problem, only at the application of the `mv` on the OPs directories. You might want to post that comment on the Q or the OP might not see that.

Comment: Certanly, I agree, it is not a problem but code will looks better.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for what you require;

`for file in $(find . -type f); do mv -- "$file" "$file-$(stat -c %Y "$file" | date +%Y%m%d)"; done`

The explain the new part, you're using the find command to only find files (type -f);

`find . -type f`.

Comment: This will change file names in subdirectories as well.

Comment: It will also fail for filenames with spaces/other special chars. Pipe to a while loop instead: `find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do ... done`

Comment: This solution will fail for a large number of files returned from the find.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop at all, just use `find` together with `exec` option + `sh -c`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$0" "$0"-$(stat -c %Y "$0" | date +%Y%m%d)' {} \;
```

However piping `stat` to `date` doesn't make much sense to me. If you want to append *current* date to all filenames then `stat` is not needed at all:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$0" "$0"-$(date +%Y%m%d)' {} \;
```

On the other hand if you want to append time of *last modification* of each file then use `-r` option of the `date`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$0" "$0"-$(date -r "$0" +%Y%m%d)' {} \;
```

And if you want to, just for exercise, use output from `stat` as an input of the `date`, then use `--date` option of `date` command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$0" "$0"-$(date +%Y%m%d --date=@$(stat -c %Y "$0"))' {} \;
```